# Default annotation route works but not the others - Symfony 4.2

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations

I'm facing a problem that I don't understand. I simply create a Controller with `make:controller` and everything works, but when I want to create a new method, my route annotation doesn't work (whereas the default one works normally). T

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/default", name="default")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'DefaultController',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     */
    public function home() {
        return $this->render('default/home.html.twig');
    }
}
```

The / route redirects me to the default page of Symfony and any other name for the route returns the `No route found` error.

Also, PHPStorm tells me that `Import' Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route is never used` when you can see that they are there...

How to solve this ? Thanks !

Comment: Still having trouble with this?  Start with "bin/console debug:router" to see if any routes are actually being defined as I assume you are just typing in urls and refreshing your browser.  And one thing to understand is that the Symfony framework itself has no default page defined.  If no routes are defined then you actually get something that looks like a page but is really more of a confusing error message.  And don't be afraid to use "bin/console cache:clear" after adding routes.  Sometimes the cache does not update.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I realized that a route already existed with this name (the rest of an old test controller...)

Comment: I have similar problem. Any method that I annotate with `@Route("/")` in my Controller works when inserting root URL to server's machine. But when I use `@Route("/foo")` (for example) and I try to go `http://server_url/foo`, I get a 404 page from Apache. And if I do `bin/console debug:router`, `/foo` is within the list... I don't get it...

Answer (score -1):

Check your config/routing.yaml

Comment: It's just `framework:
    router:
        strict_requirements: ~
        utf8: true`

Comment: This concern `config/routes/annotations.yaml` isn't it ? Because it's already in there.

Comment: Ca you post your config/routes.yaml

Comment: Empty. Just the default example in comments

Comment: I guess the annotation bundle is not installed by default anymore. Check here how to install it via composer